# Adding react routes to a working app issue

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I had a working React app, where App.js looked like this

```
const App = () => {
    return (
      <div>
         <MyFirstComponent/>
         <MySecondComponent/>
         <MyThirdComponent/>
      </div>
   )
}
```

Then I decided to add more features, so I extracted the above JSX into a separate component, NewComponent, like so

```
const NewComponent = () => {
 return (
      <div>
         <MyFirstComponent/>
         <MySecondComponent/>
         <MyThirdComponent/>
      </div>
   )
}

export default NewComponent;
```

then I introduced react router in App.js to switch between pages like so

```
const App = () => {
    return(
       <Router>//Alias for BroswerRouter from react-router-dom
          <Switch>
             <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
             <Route exact path="/old" component={NewComponent}/>
          </Switch>
       </Router>
 )
}
```

But when I run the dev server, and although the home page is displayed correctly, when I go to `http://localhost:8080/old` the old working app doesn't load, and in the console there appears this error: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`. If I add another new route like

```
...
       <Route exact path="/register" component={Registration}/>
....
```

it works fine. Only the route to my old working app doesn't work. I wonder why, as all I did was moving it to a separate component, and all relative paths were modified accordingly.

Comment: I had an issue similar when I was using a different webserver than provided by create react app. React router creates virtual pages so when you try to change the page it cannot locate it. https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#serving-apps-with-client-side-routing

Comment: I indeed use webpack dev server, but I configured the dev server to work with routes, and it does with other routes, except with the old app!